# How to print more rows from a function output

Tags: r

I am using the `waas` function in metan package and it gives me three kind of table but I can't print all the rows of the second table.
In the end of the output of the function, it appears :

```
# ... with 21 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Using `print()` I can't print all the rows. I also have seen with `tibble` but without success, can you help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `print(mydf, n=Inf)` will print all the rows. Change `Inf` to the number of rows you want displayed.

Comment: If I use it, it gives me this error: 
Error in print.default(var$individual$individual, ...) : 
  invalid 'na.print' specification

Comment: The `n` argument only works if you are looking to print data frames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print()` on the data frame output of you function and set `n` equal to the number of rows you want to see. Set `n = Inf` if you want all rows to print:

```
# \donttest{
library(metan)
model <- waas(data,
    resp = c(GY, HM),
    gen = GEN,
    env = ENV,
    rep = REP
  ) 

print(model, n = Inf)


# You can also use a pipe to print the object
# without storing it anywhere
waas(data,
    resp = c(GY, HM),
    gen = GEN,
    env = ENV,
    rep = REP
  ) |> print(n = Inf)

# }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried but it didn't work, giving me this error:
`Error in print.default(var$individual$individual, ...) : 
  invalid 'na.print' specification`